# Telling mother about miscarriage

Tags: family, southern-europe

I am the oldest child in a family of three kids. When I was a young teen, my mother announced her fourth pregnancy and I reacted badly, by crying all evening. I do not remember why this news made me so sad.

My mother miscarried a few weeks later and I felt guilty about it but I did not say anything.

Years later I was waiting with my mother for someone and she told me she had the miscarriage because of my reaction. She immediately retracted her words and said it was because of the stress she had at work. The person we were picking up arrived at that moment and we left the discussion there. Since that moment I always felt like I would never be able to have children.

A year ago I tried to talk to her about it. She did not remember the incident but she apologized. This is unusual for her, both my parents accuse us (me and my brothers) of being delusional when we recall occasions for which they were not perfect (even small stuff).

I am 25 and I just miscarried my first baby before we told anyone about the pregnancy.

**I don't know if I should talk to my mother about it**; she would either deny everything or feel guilty. I don't expect support from her but I am afraid to regret it if I ever get pregnant again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because despite how sad this story is, it is a request for advice.  That is out of scope here.  If you decide to tell your mother about it, please return and we can help you with how to talk to her about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a supportive, friendly relationship with your mother, I think you should tell her. You are going though a tough time right now, you don't need the added weight of keeping a secret from your family that is not really worth keeping.

Maybe your mother really has forgotten the exact words she said back then. If so, she probably didn't mean them anyway. If not, consider how you are feeling right now. She went through just the same. In helpless anger, your thoughts can run in weird directions, you can put blame on innocent people, just to realize later how unfair and unwarranted that was.

Comment: addition : I'm sorry for you loss. But you should also discuss this with your partner too , get their opinion and also, some causes of miscarriages are genetic, so you should get yourself tested.